# How to automatically upload Android app from Jenkins to Google Play Alpha Test?

Tags: android, build, jenkins, artifacts, automated-deployment

I have Jenkins running, pulling GitHub and building my app after each commit. There's testers community, whom I'd like to have my latest app. I'd like my app to be uploaded to Google Play Alpha Test, but maybe, I should use another service?

What you #androiddevs are using?

Comment: Since TestFlight will shutter Android support on March 21st, +1

Comment: There is no automated way of doing this so far. You can use the HockeyApp plugin for Jenkins to upload your apps there, which also has the advantage of publishing your app immediately to beta testers, rather than having to wait some unknown number of hours, as with Google Play.

Comment: Nice! Will give it a try to HockeyApp. Thanks, Christopher!

Comment: @ChristopherOrr you may want to publish that as an answer, it's a real solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [How to upload an APK from Jenkins/Hudson to Play Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507958/how-to-upload-an-apk-from-jenkins-hudson-to-play-store)

There is a new API from google to upload apks to google play, no jenkins plugin yet: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/edits/

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @ChristopherOrr alternatives, there is another TestFlight similar service which is called TestFairy (www.testfairy.com). It is also free, and they have a mobile app (in the store) so your beta testers can download the latest version directly from their phones easily.
It is also immediate as the HockeyApp.

And they provide you with a bash script which can upload your APK to TestFairy very easily.

It does something else which is recording a video with the user interactions, so when something is broken, you can have more details of what happened.

We have started using the free version at work since TestFlight went out of android business, and so far we are quite happy with it.

Comment: Recording video on rooted Android devices. Right?

Comment: It seems to work on any device. At least all the devices we have here haven't been rooted and they are used as they came, and it works. But it only records the video your application, when you go to another app, there is no video (fortunately for the sake of a little privacy :P ). I really don't how they do it!